# How do I create a FACT Table in Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pentaho, fact

Using Dimension Tables--

How do I create a FACT table in Google Big Query?

example:
PK - Dim1_ID
FK - Dim2_ID
FK - Dim3_ID
FK - Dim4_ID
FK - Dim5_ID

I need to take the dimensional tables I pulled in from Pentaho into Big Query to do the FACT table.

We tried to create a table as CREATE TABLE Dataset_Fact

But that didnt work.

example:

```
CREATE TABLE `Dataset.DimModel_FACT` (
  DimModel INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Dim1_ID INT,
  Dim2_ID INT,
  Dim3_ID INT,
  Dim3_ID INT,
  Dim4_ID INT,
  Dim5_ID INT,
  Dim6_ID INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (Dim1_ID) REFERENCES `Dataset.Dim1_ID`(Dim1_ID),
  etc
```

Comment: Where are you getting the measures for your fact table from?

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error?

Comment: @NickW: In the Dimensional Model and Datasets I have we have laid out the Fact Table.

Comment: @drum: It looks like you can't create a FACT table inside of big query

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what your comment to me means or why you think you can’t create a fact table in BQ. When you say you can’t create it, do you mean create it or do you actually mean populate it? A fact table is just a table so obviously you can create one in BQ - unless you have some specific definition of a fact table that you haven’t explained? Please can you try and update your question with a much better/more detailed explanation of what it is you are trying to do and the specific issue(s) you are facing?

Comment: Please share the log of your error in pentaho log.